# Postgresql jdbc executeUpdate() or getUpdateCount() return affected row

Tags: postgresql, function, jdbc, procedure

JDBC executeUpdate() and getUpdateCount() should return affected row number. Following java code calls a MySql stored procedure and variable "rc" is assigned to "1" which means 1 row was inserted:

```
CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("{call insertData(?)}");
stmt.setInt(1, i);
int rc = stmt.executeUpdate(); // returns 1
rc = stmt.getUpdateCount(); // returns 1
```

the MySql stored procedure called:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertData(IN i INT)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table_name(column_name) VALUES(i);
END //
```

Everything works as expected. Now want the similar Java code to work with a PostgreSql function or procedure and make executeUpdate() or getUpdateCount() act the same and return affected row. New row is inserted into Postgresql table but executeUpdate() or getUpdateCount() always return 0.

```
create procedure insertData(i integer) as $$
begin
INSERT INTO table_name(column_name) VALUES(i);
end; $$ language plpgsql;
```

How can I make executeUpdate() or getUpdateCount() return affected row when calling a Postgresql function or procedure?

Comment: Can you tell us which JDBC Postgres driver you are using?

Comment: Postgresql version 12.  <dependency><groupId>org.postgresql</groupId> <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId><version>42.2.14</version>
</dependency>